# Jquery Animation on div, remove after that

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create several divs with the id error_count dynamically. After the animation below i want them to be removed again.
The current problem is, that some divs that are created later than others, disappear earlier than they should.

```
var timer = [];
$("#"+error_count).fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut();
timer[error_count] = setTimeout(function(){
    $("#"+error_count).remove(); 
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I want it to be removed. After the fadeOut i already don't see it.

Comment: have you tried using the callback function on fadeOut,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter in the `fadeOut()` (and `fadeIn()`, for that matter) method is a callback; a function to call when the fade out has finished:

```
$("#"+error_count).fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut(200, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: +1 for using `this` instead of re-selecting the element you already have.

Answer (score 2):

Put a callback on the [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method that will delete the element after the fadeOut completes.

```
$("#" + error_count).fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut(400, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: you should call `$(this).remove();` in the callback instead of re-searching the DOM.

Comment: ... or `this.parentNode.removeChild(this)` (which is even faster) to be somehow different :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.when (
    $("#"+error_count).fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut();
).done (
    $("#"+error_count).remove();
);
```